# WordPress image size not sizing correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress admin, I have defined the size for `medium` as such:

[image]

I have then uploaded an image and defined in my code to use `medium`

`$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' );`

However, the image size is being rendered at `370 x 186px`. With the original size of the image being `1200 x 600`. Seems like the width settings are being applied, but not the height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress is maintaining the aspect ratio for the crop. 1200x600 (which is a ratio of 2:1) is downsized to 370x185 (ratio 2:1), the latter of which is rounded up to 186.

If you look at the thumbnail version there's a checkbox to crop the image exactly, however WordPress doesn't do that for the default image sizes because it is an unexpected experience. If you do want it to crop, you can manually register your own size using [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) and pass `true` for the last parameter which is crop

```php
add_action(
    'after_setup_theme',
    static function() {
        add_image_size( 'custom-medium', 370, 325, true );
    }
);
```

Comment: Didn't even consider aspect ratio! Thanks for the insight and solution :)